# Unsupervised learning algorithms to detect anomaly in waves

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, statistics, machine-learning, wave

I have a sample of graphs (more than 10000...).
that look like in the image below:
[image]

I am searching for an unsupervised learning algorithms that can help me to detect anomalous observations.

Here what I suggest for beginning: for every observation I have a collection of points $(x,y)$. With this collection, I find Fourier series with regression (I compute coefficients with the base $\{1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\dots\}$).
Now I have a set of coefficients instead of waves.

Somebody have an idea how to detect anomaly?

Comment: Do you have the data the graphs were made from, or just the graphs?

Comment: I'm not sure Fourier is the best approach. How about looking at continuity? If two values of x are close but the ys are vastly different, that could be an outlier?

Comment: @JRE I have the data.

Comment: @barrycarter But what is the statistics? How I detect anomaly with your method?

Comment: Are you looking for anomaly in a single graph or for anomal graph compared to other graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Try Nonparametric Statistics. 
You may divide your random trajectories into parts and compare their statistic characteristics (mean and variance). Smth like this (but not exactly):

http://www.cscjournals.org/manuscript/Journals/SPIJ/volume7/Issue1/SPIJ-210.pdf